# How to prevent duplicates data in resource file (.resx) from combobox selection

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, resx

How to prevent duplicates data in **resource file** (.resx) from combobox selection

like:

```
apple
mango
mango
apple
mango
grapes
```

combo-box creating duplicates value, when ever user enter the records in resx file, and select that that combo-box to verify whether the values were saved or not

Comment: Please, give some more information. [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I still can't understand how you can have duplicates in resx file, since keys cannot be duplicated. Can you post an example of how you load resources into combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Before Adding items into Combobox.
Make List of that strings. And use

```
var filtered = ResourcesList.Distinct().ToList();
```

and you have get apple mango grapes in your filtered list.
After it add items to combobox.